# Is there a CSS solution for removing spaces for non-space using languages?

Tags: html, css

Some languages don't use space. Japanese for example.

A typical paragraph might look like this (taken from [the Japanese Wikipedia article on Stack Overflow](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow))

> 本サービスはコンピュータ・プログラミングの広範囲なトピックを扱っていることが特色である。ウェブサイトは質問と回答を行う機能、またそれらに対する評価付け、wikiやdiggに似た文書の編集機能を備えており、ユーザの活発な参加を促している。Stack Overflowのユーザは良質な回答を行うことによって、評価ポイントや「バッヂ」を得ることができ、本サービスは伝統的なQ&Aサイト・フォーラムにゲーミフィケーションを施したものと言える。全てのユーザによる記述内容はクリエイティブ・コモンズライセンス下にある。

Even though there are 3 sentences in the paragraph above the only space in inside `Stack Overflow`.

So there's the issue. Japanese users generally don't write long sentences and paragraphs with no breaks. To write the paragraph above most people would not write.

```
<p>本サービスはコンピュータ・プログラミングの広範囲なトピックを扱っていることが特色である。ウェブサイトは質問と回答を行う機能、またそれらに対する評価付け、wikiやdiggに似た文書の編集機能を備えており、ユーザの活発な参加を促している。Stack Overflowのユーザは良質な回答を行うことによって、評価ポイントや「バッヂ」を得ることができ、本サービスは伝統的なQ&Aサイト・フォーラムにゲーミフィケーションを施したものと言える。全てのユーザによる記述内容はクリエイティブ・コモンズライセンス下にある。</p>
```

They'd write something more along the lines of

```
<p>
本サービスはコンピュータ・プログラミングの広範囲なトピックを扱っていることが特色である。
ウェブサイトは質問と回答を行う機能、またそれらに対する評価付け、wikiやdiggに似た文書の
編集機能を備えており、ユーザの活発な参加を促している。Stack Overflowのユーザは
良質な回答を行うことによって、評価ポイントや「バッヂ」を得ることができ、本サービスは
伝統的なQ&Aサイト・フォーラムにゲーミフィケーションを施したものと言える。全てのユーザに
よる記述内容はクリエイティブ・コモンズライセンス下にある。
</p>
```

Which unfortunately becomes this

[image: unwanted gaps]

With all these unwanted gaps

The only solution I can think of requires JavaScript to go through and remove spaces between Japanese characters and any other character at display time or by adding a build step.

Is there a CSS only solution?

Here's a live sample: The first paragraph is one long hard to edit line. The 2nd paragraph has the line breaks in it

```html
<p>
本サービスはコンピュータ・プログラミングの広範囲なトピックを扱っていることが特色である。ウェブサイトは質問と回答を行う機能、またそれらに対する評価付け、wikiやdiggに似た文書の編集機能を備えており、ユーザの活発な参加を促している。Stack Overflowのユーザは良質な回答を行うことによって、評価ポイントや「バッヂ」を得ることができ、本サービスは伝統的なQ&Aサイト・フォーラムにゲーミフィケーションを施したものと言える。全てのユーザによる記述内容はクリエイティブ・コモンズライセンス下にある。
</p>


<p>
本サービスはコンピュータ・プログラミングの広範囲なトピックを扱っていることが特色である。
ウェブサイトは質問と回答を行う機能、またそれらに対する評価付け、wikiやdiggに似た文書の
編集機能を備えており、ユーザの活発な参加を促している。Stack Overflowのユーザは
良質な回答を行うことによって、評価ポイントや「バッヂ」を得ることができ、本サービスは
伝統的なQ&Aサイト・フォーラムにゲーミフィケーションを施したものと言える。全てのユーザに
よる記述内容はクリエイティブ・コモンズライセンス下にある。
</p>
```

Here are screenshots to show the difference.

1st paragraph with no breaks in HTML

[image: no breaks]

2nd with

[image: breaks]

Also note that whatever solution it should not collapse the space in `Stack Overflow`

Comment: have you tried letter spacing? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_letter-spacing.asp

Comment: Maybe `word-spacing: -4px` could do it? One solution could be to do it with php.

Comment: Are specifically targeting Japanese or is this just used as an example? If so, what language are you targeting? Some languages would be easy to sort out, for example Korean can be fixed with `word-break: keep-all` but then again Korean has spaces so it's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: In fact, you want to find a CSS-only way to preserve line breaks, aren't you?

Comment: Might be a chrome bug, Here is my FF result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPyjj.png or actually maybe it's an FF one, because the space is there...

Comment: @Kaiido, you are right! Firefox is doing the right thing (well, what I want to happen. I wonder if this is specified or just luck). Checked Safari. It's bad. Edge fails too (and looks *horrible* to boot)

Comment: Probably luck. [css-text-3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#white-space-property) contains an informative note that suggests Firefox's behavior is correct, but it seems largely UA-dependent.

Comment: https://github.com/google/budou

Comment: Filed a bug if anyone wants to track: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753252

Answer (score -1):

Use `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap`

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kqcvp10w/

Comment: perfect to have your lines go beyond the container https://jsfiddle.net/kqcvp10w/1/

Comment: @gman: This seems to be one of the extremely exceptional cases where the inline code is enough to summarize the fiddle without having to include a copy of the same paragraph of Japanese text within the answer. A good rule of thumb to follow in any case, since, normally, [inline code is hardly enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176902/dont-consider-inline-code-spans-as-code-for-the-purposes-of-the-quality-filter)...

Comment: This doesn't work. `pre` means the lines don't flow, they just stay exactly has manually formatted. Not what I'm looking for. `pre-wrap` is even worse. Size your window smaller to see the issue.

Comment: Do you want to "artificially" remove the space?

Comment: I want paragraphs of text to be re-flowed to fit their container and to follow the Japanese rules for space collapsing which is effectively there are no spaces except between non Japanese words.